# Prevent repetition

Tags: c#, linq

The select, where orderby, take clauses and toArray() are repeated, only first line is different. How can I shorten these 3 linq queries to avoid repetition?

I have included the method used to return the view with the model

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetPopularContent(int Records, int? WorkareaRef, string Jurisdiction)
    {
        var model = new PopularContentModel();
        int? languageId = null;

        var login = new Login(HttpContext);
        var branding = new DynamicBranding(login);

        if (branding.BrandingDefaultLanguage != Cam.Service.ContentService.defaultLanguageId)
        {
            languageId = branding.BrandingDefaultLanguage;
        }

        languageId = languageId ?? ContentService.defaultLanguageId;
        var jurisdictionRef = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Jurisdiction) ? (int?)null : metaDataService.GetJurisdictionRefViaName(Jurisdiction);

        var reads24 = (await mostPopularContentService.MostPopularLast24HoursAsync(languageId.Value, WorkareaRef, jurisdictionRef, Records + 30)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Article, x=>x.Total);
        var reads7 = (await mostPopularContentService.MostPopularThisWeekAsync(languageId.Value, Records + 30)).ToDictionary(x => x.Article, x => x.Total);
        var readsShared = (await mostPopularContentService.MostSharedThisWeekAsync(languageId.Value, Records + 30)).ToDictionary(x => x.Article, x => x.Total);

        model.Read7DayDataSource = articleService.GetArticlesFromGuidList(reads7.Select(x=>x.Key), wcagOnly: branding.StrictlyWCAG2Accessible, useCache: true)
            .Select(x => new PopularArticle() { Article = x, ArticleGuid = x.ArticleGUID })
            .Where(x=> contentAdminTestingDataFilterService.AllowFirmAccess(x.Article.FirmRef, lexUser) && x.Article.RemoveDate == null)
            .OrderByDescending(x=> reads7[x.ArticleGuid])
            .Take(Records)
            .ToArray();
        model.Read24DataSource = articleService.GetArticlesFromGuidList(reads24.Select(x => x.Key), wcagOnly: branding.StrictlyWCAG2Accessible, useCache: true)
            .Select(x => new PopularArticle() { Article = x, ArticleGuid = x.ArticleGUID })
            .Where(x => contentAdminTestingDataFilterService.AllowFirmAccess(x.Article.FirmRef, lexUser) && x.Article.RemoveDate == null)
            .OrderByDescending(x => reads24[x.ArticleGuid])
            .Take(Records)
            .ToArray();
        model.SharedDataSource = articleService.GetArticlesFromGuidList(readsShared.Select(x => x.Key), wcagOnly: branding.StrictlyWCAG2Accessible, useCache: true)
            .Select(x => new PopularArticle() { Article = x, ArticleGuid = x.ArticleGUID })
            .Where(x => contentAdminTestingDataFilterService.AllowFirmAccess(x.Article.FirmRef, lexUser) && x.Article.RemoveDate == null)
            .OrderByDescending(x => readsShared[x.ArticleGuid])
            .Take(Records)
            .ToArray();

        model.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

        DecorateFirmName(model);

        model.ShowSocialButtons = branding.ShowSocialButtons;

        return PartialView("PopularContentPartial", model);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: You would create a method that takes the appropriate collection or query parameter in, and returns the appropriate array out, then reuse it. Without more information about the types involved I'm unable to provide a more specific comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your create a method that takes `reads7`, `reads24` or `readsShared` as a parameter type and returns your result:

```
IEnumerable<PopularArticle> Get(Dictionary<Guid, SOMETHING> variable)
{
    return articleService.GetArticlesFromGuidList(variable.Select(x => x.Key), wcagOnly: branding.StrictlyWCAG2Accessible, useCache: true)
        .Select(x => new PopularArticle() { Article = x, ArticleGuid = x.ArticleGUID })
        .Where(x => contentAdminTestingDataFilterService.AllowFirmAccess(x.Article.FirmRef, lexUser) && x.Article.RemoveDate != null)
        .OrderByDescending(x => variable[x.ArticleGuid])
        .Take(Records)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Example call:

```
model.Read7DayDataSource = this.Get(reads7);
```

Comment: The `.ToArray()` call is missing either in the method or on the caller